# How to remove the dynamically created 'UL', on clicking it's children? ( as well childrend need to removed)

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am creating a ul elements with li's, after clicking the li, i am getting text info from the li's. once i get the stuff, i don't what all of this parent with children, but i can't remove both..

this is my function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var  gender = ['Female','Male'],
      genderField = $('#gender');

   var genderUpdate= function(){
            genderField.focus(function(){
                if(!$('#genderList').length){
                    var topPos = $(this).position().top,lftPos = $(this).position().left;
                    $('<ul id="genderList"></ul>').css({
                        position    :'absolute',
                        top         : topPos,
                        left        : lftPos
                    }).appendTo($(this).parent());


                    $.map(gender,function(val,i){
                        $('<li>'+val+'</li>').appendTo('#genderList');
                        console.log('append');
                    })

                   $('#genderList li').live('click', function(){
                        genderField.attr('value', $(this).text());
                        $(this).parent().remove();//not removing the parent with this sibilings.
                    })

                }


            })
        }

                        genderUpdate();

})
```

here is the fiddle :

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/85DM4/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `.live()` is deprecated in JQuery 1.7+, you should use `.on()` for JQuery 1.7+ instead.
2. You do not want to change HTML Attributes with `.attr()`, attributes mostly represent default values. When you're using Javascript, you should access the current DOM properties through `.prop()`. When accessing the `value` property with JQuery, you'd rather go with the simpler `.val()` JQuery method.
   What happens is that `.attr()` used to access and set both HTML attributes and DOM properties prior to JQuery 1.6, which is no longer the case.
3. Extending on Zee Tee's answer, you can also have a predefined hidden ul which you can toggle instead of generating a new one every time the user clicks in the input box.

Do you really need an array and set the CSS dynamically? Well, I kept those characteristics, added my fixes listed above and here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85DM4/15/).

Edit: added comments to the fiddle and properly semi-colon'd it.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead:

```
     $("#genderList li").remove();
```

or

```
     $("#genderList li").hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85DM4/4/

Only problem is, it doesn't let you choose it again once you select it. I would re-evaluate some things, I would like to be able to see that window again after I selected it the first time.

Comment: what i need is, i need to remove the parent with chilren, so when gain the text box focused, it will re-create the dom again. becasue i a appending using the top and left position of text box. in case of re-size or some other adjustment it will help me lot..